# How to extract Estimate for interaction term (fixed effect) per group (random effect) in glmmTMB model

Tags: emmeans, glmmtmb

I am trying to find a way to determine the estimate for an interaction term (fixed) per group (random) for a large glmmtmb model with poisson distribution family. This is a huge dataset with a total of 61 species counted on 827 plots over 15 years.
My interest is in the influence of the disturbance parameter on the trend of each species over the recording period.

I use glmmTMB package to calculate glmms which are structured as follows:

```
model<-glmmTMB(count ~ disturbance * year + habitat.area + elevation + latitude * longitude + (1+year|ID)+(1+disturbance*year|Species), data=df, family = poisson())
```

count = yearly counts per Species

disturbance = destroyed percent of habitat area (numeric)

year = year of recording count, total data from 15 years  (numeric)

habitat.area = area of habitat per plot (ID), on which species can occur (numeric)

elevation, latitude, longitude (numeric)

ID = name of each plot (factor), total number of plots: 827

Species = name of each species (factor), total number of species: 61

Is there a way to get a species specific estimate (+SD and CI) for the fixed effect `disturbance:year`? I am interested in the effect of disturbance on trend of species.

I already tried to extract values with emtrends, but this did not work because Species is not included as fixed effect in the model.

Therefore i tired this:

```
et1<-emtrends(model, ~disturbance*year|Species, var="year", at=list(disturbance=c(1, 0,-1)))
```

With the function estimate_grouplevel I only got estimates for the random slope parameters (`Intercept`, `disturbance`, `year`, `disturbance:year`) but I am looking for a way to extract fixed effects in the first part of the model per random effect (Species).

```
estimate_grouplevel(model,type = "random")
```